# Augmented Reality on Android GPS + Interactive

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm working on a development where it is required to visualize an object by GPS and display a button to access the information of that object.

Can you develop this with android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You could develop an Camera application

Camera API

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Android docs for "controlling camera"

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

After you have an android camera app, you need a computer vision module. OpenCV is the computer vision module per excelence.

OpenCV for Android:

https://opencv.org/platforms/android/

You can do amazing things with OpenCV. This Android implementation is on java, but if you want to develop real time application, it's absolutelly recommend that you develop Android NDK application. Why? Because Android NDK use C and the native Opencv library is writed on C, then is fastest.

Although it can be done, it is not easy, you must study a lot. It depends on what features you want to extract. If you need more information, please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Suaro for your answer !! it's great!
I have been reading that there are also ways to develop AR with ionic 2. do you know anything about it ??

Comment: I'm not ionic developer... But some time ago, I found this tutorial that I found funny ... it may serve you 

https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-go-create-a-pokemon-go-style-interface-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Well done master! I'll read about android NDK and OpenCV.. I think that is very awesome!! thanks a lot